# Intent.createChooser got java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: java, android

I encountered a problem.
This is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

intent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pick");

startActivity(intent, 0);
```

But I got

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://media/external/video/media flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.android.music/.VideoBrowserActivity }
```

on many android devices.

I try to catch this exception via

```
try{
startActivity(intent, 0);
}catch(Exception ex){
//nothing to do
}
```

But it didn't work.

How can I catch this Exception to make my App not crash?

Comment: `Intent intent = intent = new Intent` is this a typo error?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when I paste my code.

Comment: hey then past your correct code

Comment: Few days gone. Does any body know how to solve?

Comment: It seems this question will not be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also encounter the similar issues, and I afraid that it couldn't be solved. so... maybe you can send the report or try another environment such as iOS.